# How to escape semicolon in C system function

Tags: c, unix

I am calling a utility program installed on Unix from a C program using `system()`. The input to call the utility program has arguments separated by semicolons, as below:

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), ". /path/to/program/env.sh && utilityname command WKS#%s\;at=%s", strmnm,dte);
            system(buffer);
```

The issue is that the arguments after the semicolon are being ignored/treated as next command. I tried escaping with '`\`' as above `\;` but it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried passing `\\\;`?

Comment: Just tried 
WKS#%s\\\;at=%s and it says warning: unknown escape sequence '\;'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`system` invokes the shell. On Unix that's most commonly either a derivative of `sh` or a derivative of `csh`. POSIX specifies only `sh` (thanks @KeithThompson). Both families of shells treat unescaped `;` as a command separator.

To escape a character according to shell rules, one would precede it with a backslash, or enclose it in quotes. C has its own rules regarding quotes and backslashes in strings, so  more backslashes are usually needed. Single quotes have a nice property of needing no backslashes in C strings.

So any of these should work:

```
"..... ';' ....."

"..... \";\" ....."

"..... \\; ....."
```

Comment: POSIX specifically requires `system()` to invoke `sh`; I don't think it will ever invoke a `csh`-derived shell (unless you tell it to, but even then `sh` will execute the `csh` command).